# Load event in React doesn't work. How to make a page loader?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, browser

I'm trying to make a page loader so I've made a `Loader` component that must add load event on `window` but it doesn't work at all:

```js
import React, {useEffect} from "react"
import './loader.sass'

const Loader = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Loading")
        window.addEventListener('load', () => console.log('Loaded'))
    }, [])
    return (
        <div id="loader">
            <div className="center">
                <div className="rect"></div>
                <div className="rect"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Loader
```

In `App.jsx` file this component is imported first so, as I think, it must render first and launch event listener, but nothing happens.

Is there something I don't understand in React render? Please tell me if you know any other way to make a page loader. I've already tried putting `addEventListener` in `index.html` file and in that case `load` event fires too early.
I've just tried Suspense and lazy, but this approach doesn't wait for styling and images.

Comment: please aeloborate why you added click listener in loader?

Comment: for debug, sry I'll edit

Comment: I'd like to recommend a more streamlined approach using `React.Suspense` and `React.lazy`, which are powerful tools provided by React for handling asynchronous component loading and rendering.

Comment: `React.Suspense` doesn't wait for images and styling, @Ian.

Comment: @Yukichi I believe I understand your request well. I will explain in detail in a follow-up reply. Please check it to make sure it meets your expectations, and if it doesn't, you may need to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

The process can be broken down into three main steps:

Step 1, Creating the Loader Component:

> In this step, you'll develop a Loader component that presents a full-screen loading animation. While the `code snippet` below provides an example using Bootstrap for illustration, you're free to use your preferred framework.

```js
const Loading = () => {
    return (
        <div className='fullscreen-overlay'>
            <div className='spinner-border text-light' role='status'>
                <span className='visually-hidden'>Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

```js
const Loading = () => {
    return (
        <div className='fullscreen-overlay'>
            <div className='spinner-border text-light' role='status'>
                <span className='visually-hidden'>Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Loading />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.fullscreen-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Loading Spinner</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Step 2: Designing a `Higher-Order Component (HOC)` and Combining with the Loader

> Here, you'll design a `HOC` and integrate it with the previously created Loader component to manage the loading behavior effectively.

```js
const withWindowLoad = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return (props) => {
        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

        useEffect(() => {
            const handleWindowLoad = () => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            };

            window.addEventListener('load', handleWindowLoad);

            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener('load', handleWindowLoad);
            };
        }, []);

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {isLoading ? <LoadingComponent /> : <WrappedComponent {...props} />}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    };
};
```

Step 3: Wrapping the Target Component with the `HOC`

> Finally, you'll utilize the `HOC` to wrap the target component, ensuring that the loading animation is displayed while the content loads.

```js
const YourComponent = () => {
    // Your component's content here
};

export default withWindowLoad(YourComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating a loader component just use this code that shows loader for 2 sec.

```
    import React, { useEffect,useState } from "react"
    import './loader.sass'
    
    const Loader = () => {
    
      const [loader, setLoader] = useState(true);
    
      useEffect(() => {

 window.addEventListener('load', () => setLoader(false))
      }, [])
    
      return (
        <>
          {loader && <div id="loader">
            <div className="center">
              <div className="rect"></div>
              <div className="rect"></div>
            </div>
          </div>}
        </>
      )
    }
    
    export default Loader
```

Comment: No, I need TRULY working page loader. I think I'll listen to @Ian

Comment: I have edited the answer as per your needs. Check it

Comment: Load event doesn't fire no matter if you use `useState` or not.